# Программное нажатие кнопки +дублирование

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("butt").click();
}
```

Он имитирует нажатие кнопки. Как вы уже заметили, я хочу, чтобы имитация этой кнопки в фрейме происходила 10 раз. Мой код не работает. Подскажите, как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Всё работает.](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lfy7c1p/)
Разве что до DOOM'а фрейма нужно добираться как-то так: `document.getElementById('iFrame').contentWindow.document`.

Comment: Спасибо! ТЕперь понял